# BOOL prints as -65

Tags: objective-c, ios, nslog, boolean

I am trying to NSLog a BOOL in Objective-C. When I do, it prints either as 0, 7, or -65. This is my code:

```
BOOL testBool;
NSLog(@"testBool = %i", testBool);
```

I've also tried %d and casting it as an int, but I get the same result every time.  Can anyone think of why this would happen?

Comment: Any more information you can give? Additional code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring it like this solved the problem:

```
BOOL testBool = NO;
```

Comment: Variables that are not initialized always potentially contain garbage. The only exception are instance variables which are automatically initialized to `0` or `nil` by the runtime.